Coding an unsaved changes check on a visualforce page
I'm very new to VF pages, so apologies if this is an obvious question.  I've built a VF page that is essentially just a big text box. I would like to throw an "Unsaved Changes" message when the page is unloaded. I understand that there's a lightening component: "lightning:unsavedChanges" that does essentially what I need, but I'm not sure how to add it to my VF. I've tried copying the sample code to no avail.
https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2021/04/12/how-to-notify-user-about-unsaved-changes-on-the-ui-using-lightning-component/
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation
I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree and this doesn't work for VF pages, or if I'm just too inexperienced to create the classes. Either way, any help or guidance would be appreciated.
Here's the code for reference:
 <apex:page standardController="Court_Appearance_Entry__c">
 <apex:includeLightning/> 
 <apex:form id="AppearanceNotes">
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>    
 <apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="Notes" label="RichTex" cols="1" ondblclick="false" 
 disabled="false" value="{!Court_Appearance_Entry__c.Notes__c}" rows="22"/><p/>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>

Thanks so much for any insight!

Visualforce basically uses standard HTML, so you can't use any of the newer technology like lightning:unsavedChanges. Instead, add a beforeunload event in your code:
<script>
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = true;
});
</script>

This will trigger the default "Do you want to leave?" message for the browser.

Hi! Thanks so much for your response. I figured I was misunderstanding something very basic about lightning:unsavedChanges. This code worked perfectly if I try to exit the tab or close the browser. If I attempt do anything within the tab (press the Home button, for instance), I'm still able to leave the page without saving. Maybe I can listen for another event other than beforeunload? Let me know if anything comes to mind, and thank you again.

Ah, additionally it's firing during the reload prompted by the save itself. So I'll press save, it asks if I would like to leave, I say yes, and it saves. Any suggestions would be great!

Update! Fixed that issue with firing on save by switching the action to quickSave and turning off the rerender. The warning message is deaf to whether or not I've actually saved, however.
